# Why LinkedList.removeFirst() = LinkedList.pop()?

Tags: java, linked-list, stack

I can not understand this.
When we call `LinkedList.add()`, we add an element to the end of the list, so if we want to mimic a stack with a linked list, we should call `LinkedList.removeLast()` for pop. I just can not understand why `removeFirst()` is used for pop?

Comment: Who told you to use removeFirst() for pop()? What language are you using?

Answer (score 6):

Assuming my psychic abilities are correct, and you're using Java:

A list (which implements Deque) can be treated as either FILO (e.g. stack) or FIFO (e.g. queue), with seperate sets of methods for each.
In either case, you remove from the front.

When treating it as a stack you use push, to add to the front.
When treating it as a queue you use add to add to the end.

Comment: I've usually heard it as FILO. To me it sounds nicer. FILO/FIFO compared to LIFO/FIFO.

Comment: As I understood it, we're more interested in how we get the outputs of the collection more than we are putting the inputs.  So it would make much more sense that we'd favor the phrase that's about getting the output first instead of getting it last.  I remember thinking the same thing when I first heard the term: "Why not put it the other way around?"  I was just told it was just universally accepted with no particular reason.  Instead, I just remembered that it was not supposed to remind me of food so it shouldn't sound like [phyllo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phyllo).  :)